# convert from serial modbus to ethernet through plc?

Tags: usb, serial, ethernet, plc

can I use a plc as a converter to convert from serial modbus(RS485) to either ethernet or usb using code ? , the plc is modicon m340 without communication module but the cpu has serial port , ethernet port and mini usb port.

i know it's easier to buy a converter and it's ridiculous use of a plc for that but i need to know the way if it can be implemented.

Answer (score 2):

Not a Modicon expert but perhaps this will point you to a solution.

First, I believe the USB port is for programming only, not fieldbus comms.  That leaves the 485 and Ethernet ports.

Look in the modicon development software for a couple of function blocks:  modbus rtu (master and slave) and for modbus/tcp.  If you can locate these, you should be able to craft a modbus rtu to modbus /tcp converter.  Hope this helps.